# Image insets getting changed itself in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a bar button item with an image. I have added it's insets using the storyboard. Now, I am hiding the bar button item using

```
if ( ques == 1 && ques == self.totalques ){
         self.nextimage.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
         self.nextimage.enabled = false
         self.previmage.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
         self.previmage.enabled = false
            }
```

When I enable the button again, the insets get lost. How can I save the insets?

Comment: Maybe they crawled out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide barbutton image like this -

```
barBtn.image=nil
```

For showing with insets, try this -

```
var myImage = UIImage(named: "arrow.jpg")!
let myInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)
myImage = myImage.resizableImageWithCapInsets(myInsets)
barBtn.image = myImage
```

Hope this works for you!